# runtime error 2147467259(80004005) ODBC SQL server does not exist or access denied

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. When I try to execute this piece of code (written by someone else) I get an error at `objMyconn.open`:

```
Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command

Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set dependenciesRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

dependenciesRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient 

objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL;Driver=SQL Server;Server=aac-
srvsqldb02\db02;Database=mydatabase;UID=webreport;PWD=abcdefghijkl;"
objMyConn.Open
```

Comment: Is your Connectionstring correct? 
Do you have access to the db server location from the machine you're running on at all?

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: Look into the log file of the SQL Server.

Comment: @H.A Indeed, check the SQL Server log. First try to open the db from the machine you're executing the VBA on with SSMS or something to see if you can access the server at all.

Comment: sentences improvements

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the Driver name should be between {} eg :`Driver={SQL Server}`